# String selection from Matrix data

Tags: matlab

I need a little help from you Matlab experts.

I have a cell array (Names) with a list of 14 different names. Then I have a 15x3 matrix (Selection) with some random numbers from 0-14.

Now what I want to do is use each row in the "selection" matrix to make a list of names corresponding to the number in each cell. As an example the first row is [1 3 12] shall make thes list of names {Dave Smith Niko}. The third row is [9 2 0] and should result in the list {Chris Andy}.
It's ok to get the name list's out in a combined 15x3 cell array for instance from a loop.

PLEASE help me sort this out. Thanks

```
Names = {   
    'Dave'
    'Andy'
    'Smith'
    'Eric'
    'Donna'
    'Lisa'
    'Gawin'
    'Bill'
    'Chris'
    'Crystal'
    'Beth'
    'Niko'
    'Conny'
    'Clara'
}
Selection = [
       1     3    12;
       3     6     8;
       9     2     0;
       4     2     1;
       8     5     7;
       3     2     0;
       4     7     1;
       4     9    12;
       0     0     0;
       0     0     0;
       0     0     0;
       0     0     0;
       0     0     0;
       0     0     0;
       0     0     0;
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Names(Selection(3,Selection(3,:)~=0))
```

Or, using variable:

```
rownum = 3;Names(Selection(rownum,Selection(rownum,:)~=0))
```

Results into:

```
ans = 
'Chris'
'Andy'
```

If used on row of zeros:

```
rownum = 10;Names(Selection(rownum,Selection(rownum,:)~=0))

ans = 
Empty cell array: 0-by-1
```